# Backbone View Attribute set for next Instantiation?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view that has a `tooltip` attribute. I want to set that attribute dynamically on `initialize` or `render`. However, when I set it, it appears on the next instantiation of that view instead of the current one:

```
    var WorkoutSectionSlide = Parse.View.extend( {      
        tag : 'div',
        className : 'sectionPreview',
        attributes : {},

        template : _.template(workoutSectionPreviewElement),

        initialize : function() {
//          this.setDetailsTooltip(); // doesn't work if run here either
        },

        setDetailsTooltip : function() {
            // build details
            ...

            // set tooltip
            this.attributes['tooltip'] = details.join(', ');
        },

        render: function() {            
            this.setDetailsTooltip(); // applies to next WorkoutViewSlide

            // build firstExercises images
            var firstExercisesHTML = '';
            for(key in this.model.workoutExerciseList.models) {
                // stop after 3
                if(key == 3)
                    break;
                else
                    firstExercisesHTML += '<img src="' +
                        (this.model.workoutExerciseList.models[key].get("finalThumbnail") ?
                                this.model.workoutExerciseList.models[key].get("finalThumbnail").url : Exercise.SRC_NOIMAGE) + '" />';
            }

            // render the section slide
            $(this.el).html(this.template({
                workoutSection : this.model,
                firstExercisesHTML : firstExercisesHTML,
                WorkoutSection : WorkoutSection,
                Exercise : Exercise
            }));


            return this;
        }
    });
```

Here is how I initialize the view:

```
// section preview
$('#sectionPreviews').append(
    (new WorkoutSectionPreview({
        model: that.workoutSections[that._renderWorkoutSectionIndex]
    })).render().el
);
```

How can I dynamically set my `attribute` (tooltip) on the current view, and why is it affecting the *next* view?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

```
var WorkoutSectionSlide = Parse.View.extend( {      
    tag : 'div',
    className : 'sectionPreview',
    attributes : {} // <----------------- This doesn't do what you think it does
```

Everything that you put in the `.extend({...})` ends up in `WorkoutSectionSlide.prototype`, they aren't copied to the instances, they're shared by all instances through the prototype. The result in your case is that you have one `attributes` object that is shared by all `WorkoutSectionSlide`s.

Furthermore, the view's [`attributes`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-attributes) are only used while the the object is [being constructed](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1168):

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
  this._configure(options || {});
  this._ensureElement();
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  this.delegateEvents();
};
```

The [`_ensureElement`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1291) call is the thing that uses `attributes` and you'll notice that it comes before `initialize` is called. That order combined with the prototype behavior is why your attribute shows up on the *next* instance of the view. The `attributes` is really meant for static properties, your `this.$el.attr('tooltip', ...)` solution is a good way to handle a dynamic attribute.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I've updated my `initialize` to exactly that and am not getting the desired result :(

Comment: @Garrett: What's reading `attributes`? I don't see anything that accesses it in your code.

Comment: I fixed it with `this.$el.attr('tooltip', ...)`, but would like to know if there is a better solution. Thanks for your insight, I appreciate your endless dedication to SO (and most of my questions).
I am using `attributes` to set attributes on the `el` so my final result is `<div class="sectionPreview" tooltip="...">...</div>`.

Comment: @Garrett: Right, that [`attributes`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-attributes), shows you which parts of Backbone I never use, eh? I've fixed up the answer and using `this.$el.attr(...)` is a perfectly valid thing to do and probably the only sensible thing to do. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. I actually stepped through that code but didn't catch that =S You learn something new every day. I learn *many* haha.

Comment: @Garrett: Answering questions is how I learn a lot of what I know so thanks to you too :)

Answer (score 7):

You can define `attribute` property as a function that returns object as result. So you're able to set your attributes dynamically.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    tagName: 'article',
    className: 'someClass',
    attributes: function(){
        return {
            id: 'model-'+this.model.id,
            someAttr: Math.random()
        }
    }
})
```

I hope it hepls.